# CSS animation - cut text in middle

Tags: html, css, animation, effect

i have found that page where is used animation effect in nav menu after hover.

https://haimbenisty.com/

I have no idea how to do it.. I have tested some CSS, but a was only able to make a stroke true text. Does anyone know how to do it? I really like that effect, text looks like it cut in middle.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```css
h1:hover{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
    }
h1:after, h1:hover{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:2px;
  left:0; top:17px;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>EXAMPLE</h1>
```